# Reading XML data in java in generic way

Tags: java, xml

How to read data from a XML file in a generic way.generic way means in the sense idf I change the XML file at a later time no impact will be there to the out put format.
It should read the whole content of the XML file perfectly in key value pair.

Comment: Please give a (minimal) concrete example of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: suppose now I have a xml file like

Comment: suppose now I have a xml file like <company name="IBM"><employee><name>Bravo</name><designation>se</designation></employee></company> now I have to read this like company name:IBM employee name:bravo designation:se right. in future i modified the xml file like i add <contact>8123921373</contact>.ok.but the same program must be able to read and parse the xml file same as previous way.like key value pair.

Answer (score 0):

You should try with a SAX Parser and put the key/value pairs in a Map.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html

Using this Handler you can simply parse it from start to end.

See also [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/) for an example.